# How do I use the surface current version of the Biot-Savart Law to calculate the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

This is the formula: $$1/4\pi*\int_{<s>}\vec{J_s}\times \vec{R}/(R^2)ds$$

How would I apply it to figure out the magnetic field at a point in the middle of an infinitely long sheet with width w at a height h away? How do I do this area integral? I get y goes from -infinity to infinity so the integral becomes infinity+infinity. How do I deal with the dy term?

Comment: Which dimension is $y$?

Comment: @garyp The thing has width w and is infinitely long, and dy goes from -infinity to infinity, so it is the side of infinite length

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you mean by "infinity+infinity".  I suspect that the $1/R^2$ dependence keeps the integral finite.  Show us how you conclude that the integral is infinite.

Comment: @garyp I thought R was $\vec{x}+\vec{z}$ multiplied by some constant for each term. If it includes y, then it is not infinite, but otherwise it will be. Does R include y terms?

Comment: Does the current flow lengthwise or breadthwise?